# Invocability of functors

Tags: c++, c++20

Why does the standard not consider functors with a ref-qualified call operator to be invocable?

```
#include <concepts>
    
struct f   { auto operator()()        {} };
struct fr  { auto operator()() &      {} };
struct fcr { auto operator()() const& {} };
struct frr { auto operator()() &&     {} };

static_assert(std::copy_constructible<f>);   // ok
static_assert(std::copy_constructible<fr>);  // ok
static_assert(std::copy_constructible<fcr>); // ok
static_assert(std::copy_constructible<frr>); // ok

static_assert(std::invocable<f>);   // ok
static_assert(std::invocable<fr>);  // fails
static_assert(std::invocable<fcr>); // ok
static_assert(std::invocable<frr>); // ok
```

Well it might have something to do with `std::declval` returning a temporary object, I don't feel an implementation detail as such should be relevant to the user. Semantically, the functors in the [example code](https://godbolt.org/z/znWvcd84e) should not be regarded differently in terms of invocability.

Also, why does there appear to be this contradiction between what `std::invocable` and `std::function` consider to be a `callable` object?

```
#include <functional>

using tf   = decltype(std::function{f{}});   // ok
using tfr  = decltype(std::function{fr{}});  // ok
using tfcr = decltype(std::function{fcr{}}); // ok
using tfrr = decltype(std::function{frr{}}); // fails
```

---

Just to muddy the waters even further, it also seems that MVSC v19.32 accepts the [following code](https://godbolt.org/z/P4vbo1qG5). Is that simply a compiler bug of MSVC?

```
template<std::invocable F>
auto g() -> void {}

using tg   = decltype(g<f>);   // ok
using tgr  = decltype(g<fr>);  // ok
using tgcr = decltype(g<fcr>); // ok
using tgrr = decltype(g<frr>); // ok
```

Comment: I didn't test but maybe `std::invocable<fr&>` will work?

Comment: The `std::invoke` concept uses an rvalue-ref object to test for invoke-ability. I haven't checked, I believe that `const &`-qualified function can be invoked for an rvalue-ref object, but an `&`-qualified function cannot be, hence the difference (and obviously an `&&`-qualified function can be). `std::function` copies the passed-in object, and is an entirely different ballgame.

Comment: @user202729 It makes the assertion pass but the problem remains that a user might be really surprised to see his type-constraint fail when writing generic code.

Comment: Depends on what you want exactly though? If you want to test if operator() is callable on a lvalue object then use the & check, if you want to test if operator() is callable on a rvalue object then use the normal one...?

Comment: @user202729 Well, why wouldn't `std::invocable` work in all cases? It's quite understandable that this is the expected behavior. Why should it be expected that a functor with an `operator()() &&` gets special treatment while a functor with an `operator()() &` does not? There is nothing stated about this in the standard library.

Comment: I don't get your point? The standard (I don't actually have the standard, so cppreference) says "determines whether INVOKE(std::declval<Fn>(), std::declval<ArgTypes>()...) is well formed" where declval is defined with " the return type is T&&"  -- and you inceded cannot call `operator()` on a `fr&&` instance.

Comment: @303 If `std::invocable` was satisfied both if the object can be called with an rvalue argument _or_ with an lvalue argument, then it would be useless, because it wouldn't tell you whether `auto x = fr{}; x();` will work or whether `fr{}()` will work. The way it is specified `std::invocable<fr>` tells you whether the latter works and `std::invocable<fr&>` tells you whether the former works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fails:

```cpp
static_assert(std::invocable<fr>);  // fails
```

Because it is testing the validity of the expression `std::invoke(std::declval<fr>())`, which is trying to invoke an *rvalue* of type `fr`. But `fr`'s call operator is `&`-qualified, which means you can only invoke it on an lvalue. That's why it's being rejected.

> Why does the standard not consider functors with a ref-qualified call operator to be invocable?

It's not that it doesn't consider them to be invocable, *period*. It's that the value category also plays a role in `std::invocable`. You can see that if you tried:

```cpp
static_assert(std::invocable<fr&>);  // ok
```

This is because now we're testing to see if `fr` can be invoked as an lvalue (which it can), as opposed to as an rvalue (which it cannot).

Comment: Alright, I can see the necessity of this distinction
but I don't find this situation to be very user friendly when having to rewrite `template<std::invocable F> auto g() {}` to
`template<typename F> requires std::invocable<F> or std::invocable<F&> auto g() {}`
when attempting `using r = decltype(g<fr>);`
due to error `cannot resolve address of overloaded function`.

Comment: Where `template<std::invocable F> void g() {}` actually seems to compile only on MSVC, interestingly enough.

Comment: @303 `std::invocable F` and `requires std::invocable<F>` mean the same thing. The "cannot resolve address" part is unrelated to the question of how to spell the invocable constraint you want.

Comment: The point is, when seeing something like `std::invocable F`, one might expect the constraint to be satisfied with any sort of callable type that takes no parameters, which it does except for a callable type that has a ref-qualified call operator. I'm arguing that this exception can be rather surprising, especially when being confronted with a seemingly unrelated error like `cannot resolve address`. Having the main stream compilers disagree about this behavior doesn't really help either.

Comment: @303 It's not an "exception" - that's what that constraint actually means (your expectation is wrong). And not any ref-qualified call operator, specifically an lvalue ref-qualified operator - because what that check actually means is that the callable is rvalue-callable with no parameters. As far as I can tell, all compilers agree on the behavior here - do you have an example in which they don't?

Comment: You can find the example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/P4vbo1qG5). If you address the others issues mentioned in my post, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @303 msvc still rejects `g<fr>()`, it looks like in this specific context msvc just doesn't check the the constraints at all.